# Graphviz, How to center the arrow (make a straight line) between two nodes?

Tags: graphviz, dot

Currently, I have this plot which looks fine for me except for the arrow connecting X and Y directly.
[image]

This is the plot I'd like to draw where the arrow is about in the center, I had one solution which is to create an invisible node in the middle, but just wondering if there is a better way, since I feel it can be done easily.

[image]

Here are my codes:

```
digraph{
      graph [rankdir=LR]
      node [shape = plaintext]
      {rank=same; X1;X2;X3;X4;X5}
      X -> X1 -> Y;
      X -> X2 -> Y;
      X -> X3 -> Y;
      X -> Y;
      X -> X4[dir=back];
      X -> X5[dir=back];
      X4 -> Y;
      X5 -> Y;}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Graphviz tries to keep nodes on a straight line in rank direction if nodes belong to the same group.

```
digraph{
    graph [rankdir=LR]
    node [shape = plaintext]
    X1;X2;X3
    X[group=mid_straight];
    Y[group=mid_straight];
    X4;X5;
    X -> X1 -> Y;
    X -> X2 -> Y;
    X -> X3 -> Y;
    X -> Y;
    X -> X4[dir=back];
    X -> X5[dir=back];
    X4 -> Y;
    X5 -> Y;
}
```

[image]

if you want to have straight lines setting splines might be sufficient

```
digraph{
    graph [rankdir=LR splines=line]
    node [shape = plaintext]
    {rank=same; X1;X2;X3;X4;X5}
    X -> X1 -> Y;
    X -> X2 -> Y;
    X -> X3 -> Y;
    X -> Y;
    X -> X4[dir=back];
    X -> X5[dir=back];
    X4 -> Y;
    X5 -> Y;
}
```

[image]